# PHP Registation: Checking E-Mail exists

Tags: php

I've decided to try and build a simple Login and Register form but I have ran into a problem.

When someone Signs Up I obviously ask them to fill in a `Name`, `E-Mail`, `Password`, and `Confirm Password`.

I am checking if the E-Mail is already in the database by using the following code:

```
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email ='" . $_POST['email'] . "'");
$query->execute();

if ( $query->rowCount() > 0 ) {
    $error = true;
    $email_again = "E-Mail already exists";
}
```

My Problem:

Well say at the minute when someone enters an E-Mail that is already in the database the page refreshes and shows them the error.

Now the database doesn't add it into the table but what it does do is increment the id's by one so next time someone Signs up with a valid E-Mail instead of their id being 2 it is 3 because someone tried to Sign up with an E-Mail already in there

```
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email ='" . $_POST['email'] . "'");
$query->execute();

if ( $query->rowCount() > 0 ) {
    $error = true;
    $email_again = "E-Mail already exists";
    exit();
}
```

So I went ahead and added `exit();` to the `if` statement but then it just displays a blank page after submit if the E-Mail is already in the database.

How can I solve this?

**Update**:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'me@stephenhinett.co.uk' for key 'email' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tasks/register.php:69 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tasks/register.php(69): PDO->exec('INSERT INTO use...') #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tasks/register.php on line 69
```

Line 69:

```
$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO users(name, email, password)
        VALUES ('" . $name . "', '" . $email . "', '" . md5($password) . "')";
$conn->exec($sql_insert);
```

Comment: If you don't insert an entry then auto-incremented identifiers shouldn't increment. The exit you're doing is probably a botch fix to another more serious issue.

Comment: @apokryfos updated my question to show the error message I am getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem 1**

> ```
> if ( $query->rowCount() > 0 ) {
>     $error = true;
>     $email_again = "E-Mail already exists";
>     exit();
> }
> ```
>
> So I went ahead and added exit(); to the if statement but then it just displays a blank page after submit if the E-Mail is already in the database.

Your issue is while you added `exit` you did not add a `header` to tell the browser what to output, if anything. And an `exit` without output will always be a white screen of dullness. `Exit` ceases the script at that point, and so is not often very user friendly, in isolation.

So, add a header before the exit so your page can correctly redirect the user. I have also added a `$_SESSION` variable holding the message you want to feed back to your user (about the email duplication):

```
session_start(); //if not already started at the top of the page
if ( $query->rowCount() > 0 ) {
        $error = true;
        $_SESSION['message'] = "E-Mail already exists.";
        header("Location: somepage.php"); //will display session message
        exit();
    }
```

And on the page you go to, set a system to chec the sessio values for the message and output the message to the browser window.

**Problem 2**

Read your problem error: You are trying to duplicate a unqiue key (`email`) index in the database table, the duplicated email is still being (attempted) `INSERT`ed by some script function.

You have not shown us this script function (on register.php line 69) so I can't say much more about the details of this, but you may be interested to use [On Dupliate Key Update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax to help you overcome this.

**Side note(s):**

- If you're already using Object Orientated Notation for your SQL, why are you not using [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)? This is far more secure, as well as more efficient way of checking if the email already exists in the database table.
- I don't understand why you want to increment a row id upon an attempted email duplication, why increment the `id` field? If the id value is your Primary Key (PK) and is a MySQL *`auto_increment`* then to ***manually*** increment this is very bad practise and will cause you all sorts of related issues. Better to have another table column such as `repetation_attempts` which is a standard `tinyint(3)` (or `smallint(6)`, whatever) column (default zero) which will then be updated to track how many duplication attempts have been tried on any given email row.

  - An id column is an ***id***entification column and should not be used as a *counter*.

Answer (score 0):

for security reasons I recommend you to use Prepared Statements.
I'm not a MySQL expert but I think this is the situation...

The autoincrement index will increment also on failed insert statements for concurrency reasons:

> 1. Query A do an INSERT statement and the DB reserve an index
> 2. Query B do an INSERT statement and the DB reserve an index
> 3. Query A fails but "B" complete his statement and it's concurrent
> 4. To guarantee the consistency the index of A will be simply wasted

As you said, you can check manually if the E-Mail already exists.
Pseudo code:

> ```
> if(mail_already_exists()){
>     show_error();
> }else{
>     insert_data();
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> the database doesn't add it into the table but what it does do is
>   increment the id's by one so next time someone Signs up with a valid
>   E-Mail instead of their id being 2 it is 3 because someone tried to
>   Sign up with an E-Mail already in there

I see no reason why ID will get incremented unless you actually INSERT data. Use a function for duplicate record checking.

1. Check if EMAIL exists. If exists, return TRUE , else FALSE
2. If TRUE (email exists), throw a message to user
3. if FALSE, do the INSERT job.